# Does isomorphism of affine varieties preserve closed sets and open sets?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, affine-varieties

I am wondering if I have a isomorphism of affine varieties does it preserve closed sets?

(I am trying to understand why $g \overline{H} = \overline{gH}$ where $G$ is an affine algerbraic group and $H$ is an abstract subgroup of $G$ and $g \in G$)

Comment: An isomorphism of varieties is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @A.Rod I guess morphism of affine varieties is by definition continuous ?

Comment: Well a morphism of ringed space is by definition continuous. A fortiori a morphism of affine varieties.